# Autocomplete for single word in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, autocomplete

I would need to implement a autocomplete feature in a datagridview cell. I would need it to work on a word by word basis, like it is in the SMS app on android. After I type a whitespace it should start looking for the word I am typing and propose it based on the other words i have already used inside the same Datagridview.

Its more a word suggestion, that if i hit tab autocompletes that word for me.

Is this possible? I know how to do it based on the entire cell, but have no clue on how to do it based on the single word. (like Google)

Thanks

EDIT:

So far I have this. The concept is working, but I need to update the list each time that a key is pressed. Any help on this?

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.EditingControlShowing

        wrdlst.Add("arabia")
        wrdlst.Add("burundi")
        wrdlst.Add("closed")
        wrdlst.Add("afganistan")
        wrdlst.Add("door")
        wrdlst.Add("banana")
        wrdlst.Add("apple")


    Dim basestring As String = Nothing
    basestring = CStr(DataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value)
    If Not IsNothing(basestring) Then
        Dim lastword As String
        Dim lastspaceindex As Integer = basestring.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1 '''+1 to get index after whitespace and compensate for -1 result

        lastword = basestring.Substring(lastspaceindex)

        Dim ItemCode As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)

        If ItemCode IsNot Nothing Then
            ItemCode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            'ItemCode.AutoCompleteCustomSource = wrdlst

            For Each element As String In wrdlst
                If element.StartsWith(lastword) Then
                    ItemCode.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(basestring.Substring(0, lastspaceindex) & element)
                End If
            Next

            ItemCode.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

        End If
    End If

End Sub

  Private Sub DataGridView2_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.KeyUp


 ??????????????????????????????????????????


End Sub
```